# Async REST Update on missing object

Tags: rest, asynchronous

I have a REST API that allows a client to asynchronously create and update entities.

Recently, we ran into an issue where the REST client tried to update an entity that had been deleted.
Due to the async nature, they received a 202 (the update data was valid).

I'm trying to determine best practice here. Our REST API is a public frontend on a legacy system. We could check if the entity exists (and is editable, permissions, etc) but that will slow down the 95% of requests that are valid. 
OTOH it feels wrong to return a 202 for a request to update a non-existent entity.

What is best practice here?

Comment: 202 seems OK, presumably the client finds out that entity didn't exist any more by polling the returned Location.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yeah, they do. It just means they find it out later instead of straight away. :(

Comment: Well you can't have both! Be consistent with the other ways you tell clients "actually we couldn't apply that".